# Setting up fitnesse with waferslim for python

Tags: python, fitnesse

I have got fitnesse working with java, now i want to try it with python.

am trying to use waferslim, currently to no avail.

I have been trying to follow this guide:
http://withaherring.blogspot.co.nz/2009/03/using-waferslim-with-fitnesse.html

I am still starting the server using the following:

```
java -jar fitnesse-standalone.jar -p 8081
```

then the script I have on the page is:

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim} 
!path /home/calum/python/test-fit/app.py
!define COMMAND_PATTERN {python3 -m waferslim.server --syspath %p }

|Calc|
|A      |B      |multiply?  |
|1      |2      |2          |
|1      |0      |0          |
|3      |5      |15         |
```

When I run this I get quite a long stack trace that doesnt make alot of sense to me. (can provide if it will be helpful to work out the issue)

then I tried just running the command from the command line:

```
python3 -m waferslim.server --syspath '/home/calum/python/test-fit/app.py'
```

which gives me the following trace:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/runpy.py", line 160, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/runpy.py", line 73, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/waferslim/server.py", line 164, in <module>
    start_server()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/waferslim/server.py", line 161, in start_server
    WaferSlimServer(options).serve_forever()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/waferslim/server.py", line 85, in __init__
    server_address = (options.inethost, int(options.port))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'`

Could anyone suggest where I have gone wrong?

thanks

Comment: could u solve that? I am sung waferslim and getting exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

try to set Path as /home/calum/python, and introduce import as below:

|import|

|test-fit.app|

Answer (score 0):

Fitnesse takes the command pattern you have provided and appends a port number to it. When you run from the command line, try

```
python3 -m waferslim.server --syspath '/home/calum/python/test-fit/app.py' 1234
```

This should bring up a Slim server listening on port 1234.